# How to override the unlink method of 'res.partner' model? Odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I want to remove the condition that generates the UserError in unlink method of 'res.partner' model:

```
def unlink(self):
    running_sessions = self.env['pos.session'].sudo().search([('state', '!=', 'closed')])
    if running_sessions:
        raise UserError(
            _("You cannot delete contacts while there are active PoS sessions. Close the session(s) %s first.")
            % ", ".join(session.name for session in running_sessions)
        )
    return super(ResPartner, self).unlink()
```

I try by this code , but it always execute the standard function :

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'


    def unlink(self):
        running_sessions = self.env['pos.session'].sudo().search(
    [('state', 'not in', ['opening_control', 'opened', 'closing_control', 'closed'])])
        if running_sessions:
            raise UserError(
        _("You cannot delete contacts while there are active PoS sessions. Close the session(s) %s first.")
        % ", ".join(session.name for session in running_sessions)
    )
        else:
            return ResPartner.unlink(self)
```

How can I do it ? Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code here is correct

> I try by this code , but it always execute the standard function :

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
      def unlink(self):
            return super(ResPartner, self).unlink()
```

And you ask it to execute the standard method.

--- Edit ---

After re-reading question, I understood that you want to overwrite integrity check that point of sale module implements. This isn't good idea. You should obey that restriction. There is a good reason for that.

Instead, mark partner inactive or add a column to mark partner to be removed when conditions allows you to do it.

for example

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    remove_me = fields.Boolean('Marked for removal')
    def unlink(self):
        try:
          return super(ResPartner, self).unlink()
        except UserError:
          # If partner cannot be removed mark it as inactive and for removal
          self.remove_me = True
          self.active = False
```

And then create some scheduled action to remove partners marked for removal. Or leave them in database as inactive. You cannot remove a res.partner object anyway if there is any other object which has reference to it.  And removing data from ERP systems is always a bit suspicious.

Comment: I updated my post , now , I got this error : 
 Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Current thread 0x00007f26b51fe700 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 430 in usesTime
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 588 in usesTime
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 620 in format
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/netsvc.py", line 104 in format
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 880 in format
................................

Comment: In your updaed question your unlink methond is outside of your class. Is your code like that. You should indent `def unlin(self):` and everything inside it one step further.

Comment: it is correct in my code , just I made a mistake in this post , updated. So, same error.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@api.model` annotation and the `super` method.

That's all, you can find example if search for `@api.model` in original odoo directory

Comment: It's good for you?

Answer (score -2):

Try below example of code to replace unlink method of specific file.

```
from odoo.addons.point_of_sale.models.res_partner import ResPartner

def unlink(self):
    running_sessions = self.env['pos.session'].sudo().search([('state', '!=', 'closed')])
    if running_sessions:
        pass
    return super(ResPartner, self).unlink()

ResPartner.unlink = unlink
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea in Odoo.

Comment: But, I have tried to show the possibilities in this way.It is up to you to decide whether or not to use it.

Comment: @ex4 why is it a bad idea, from what I understand what is asked is to remove this exception not add it

Comment: It is against Odoo coding guidelines. See https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/13_inheritance.html

Comment: @Siddharth Tarpada, When trying this ,  I got this error : Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. Current thread 0x00007f26b51fe700 (most recent call first): File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 430 in usesTime File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 588 in usesTime File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 620 in format File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/netsvc.py", line 104 in format File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 880 in format ................................